# swap first name and last name and then group by

Tags: r

I have a vector that contains person name with duplicates. (Not in proper order. First name and last name are interchanged sometimes)

```
name <- c('jimmy fallows','fallows jimmy','brad pitt','clark michael','michael clark')
```

I need to get the unique names from the vector.

Desired Output:

```
 c('jimmy fallows','brad pitt','michael clark')
```

`unique(name)` doesn't address this. I have tried using `strsplit` but this swaps all the names in the vector. I have to pick the right ones to swap.

```
testfunct <- function(x){  
  splt <- strsplit(x, ' ')  
  swap <- paste(splt[[1]][2],splt[[1]][1])  
  swap
}
unique(lapply(name,testfunct))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `sort` on the `split` `list` elements and then with `duplicated` get a `logical` vector to extract the `unique` elements of 'name'

```
name[!duplicated(lapply(strsplit(name, "\\s+"), sort))]
```